# Checkstyle outputting a lot of debug statements

Tags: java, checkstyle

I can't figure out what is causing this.

No change to configuration files seem to have happened, though something must be different, as it used to not output stuff like this:

```
...
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Byte value '0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value:  
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Character' value ' ' to type 'Character'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:149)     No conversion required, value is already a Character
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Double'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Double value '0.0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Float'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Float value '0.0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,889 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Integer'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:149)     No conversion required, value is already a Integer
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Long'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Long value '0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Short'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Short value '0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0.0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'BigDecimal' value '0.0' to type 'BigDecimal'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:149)     No conversion required, value is already a BigDecimal
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'BigInteger' value '0' to type 'BigInteger'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:149)     No conversion required, value is already a BigInteger
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: false
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Boolean' value 'false' to type 'Boolean'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:149)     No conversion required, value is already a Boolean
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Byte'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Byte value '0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,890 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value:  
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Character' value ' ' to type 'Character'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:149)     No conversion required, value is already a Character
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Double'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Double value '0.0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Float'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:158)     Converted to Float value '0.0'
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:setDefaultValue:336) Setting default value: 0
11 Jan 2017 15:30:46,891 [DEBUG] (AbstractConverter.java:convert:127) Converting 'Integer' value '0' to type 'Integer'
...
```

Googling it gives nothing. Something must have changed, but I've had no luck finding out what, or finding out what controls this behavior. Can someone point me to where the configuration for this is usually found?

EDIT: After looking in to BeanUtils, I came across this bit of source code: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/AbstractConverter.html

In which I find all the output statements, surrounded by this:

```
if (log().isDebugEnabled()) {
    log().debug(...
}
```

So apparently this return `true`. I don't see how that's possible. Now I need to find out how to turn it off.

I'm using the Play Framework, which uses logback. There is no log4j properties file.

EDIT: Started a bounty on this, because it's really annoying that I can't find a solution anywhere. All google gives me is either source code or other people's logs. I've tried turning off the namespaces and classes in the logback configuration but that didn't work. I've tried setting everything to ERROR and OFF but that didn't work either. I'm out of ideas and the fact that I can't find the solution to this anywhere is really annoying. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The build tool is play, which is a wrapper around sbt. The configuration for checkstyle is done like this: https://github.com/ymasory/play-pmd-checkstyle/blob/master/project/Build.scala

With the exact same commandline options as in the exameple script. Also in a Build.scala file.

And then you run `play checkstyle` and that outputs it.

The configuration XML for checkstyle looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  <module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="project/suppressions.xml"/>
  </module>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocType"/>
    <module name="JavadocVariable"/>
    <module name="JavadocStyle"/>
    <module name="ConstantName"/>
```

And more modules as that that, till the end of the file.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it's coming from checkstyle? Searching their repo for [`AbstractConverter`](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AbstractConverter) didn't produce any results.

Comment: This seems more like BeanUtils.

Comment: @DaveNewton It seems I have debug enabled for the apache logger, but I can't find any setting at all in my project that sets this. And it didn't use to happen.

Comment: it's called JMX, you can set it there. Someone set it to true, so now you in debug mode, and it produces all this code :) Don't ask me how to - never trued, can't help with that, just know what it is

Comment: What build tool are you using? What command are you using to build, where are you running it from, and what are the (relevant) environmental settings in play? What is your (relevant) checkstyle config? What other (relevant) build plugins are you using?

Comment: @Bohemian I updated the question. I don't think anything at all is being set from play to checkstyle, outside of the settings detailed in that Build.scala file I linked in the updated question. Also added the checkstyle config. No other build plugins are being used, the command is run from the folder the project resides in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the log level with a log4j.xml file. If you see the documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger#Configuring-logging) , you will notice that the play framework uses SLF4J as its default logger. This means it should be able to be configured in the exact same way as you would log4j.properties.If you read the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html#Configuration) here you should be able to suppress it if you do something like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
<PACKAGE>.checkstyle=WARN
```

Replace  with the package that you are trying to replace. So for example if you are trying to suppress `java.lang.String` you would replace  with `java.lang`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I should replace <PACKAGE> with. The apache library or my own packages?

Comment: Apache library, i.e. something like `org.apache.commons.beanutils`.

Comment: Alright, I created a log4j xml file from an example, set the root logger to ERROR and forced that xml file on to play with an extra commanline parameter. While not exactly your answer, it did put me on the right path. Still in the dark about what caused this to happen in the first place, but the problem I came here for is now fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `-d` or `--debug` option in Checkstyle, this will result in JDK Log level `FINEST` which in turn will be interpreted as "debug enabled" by Beanutils.

Comment: Updated the question with details on the checkstyle configuration. Not using the debug statement.

Comment: Then try to find out who/what sets your JDK or Log4J log level.